# How to get response object from a Requests GET call when it throws an exception

Tags: python, python-requests

How can I get the response object back from a request when it throws an exception?

Essentially, I'm trying to make a request via a proxy and the proxy is giving back a 302 code (this is what I want). However, after some debugging, I discovered that inside the `requests` library, it expects a 200 code from the proxy and will throw an exception otherwise.

Here is the command I'm executing:

```
session.get(url=url, headers=req_headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, timeout=30)
```

This gives me a `(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 302 Object Moved'))`. This is the correct behavior I'm expecting from my proxy but I need the response object because the response object has useful info that I need in my logic and right now I'm only able to get the error msg. Is there a way I can still get the response object without having to modify the `requests` library?

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

```
def _tunnel(self):
    connect_str = "CONNECT %s:%d HTTP/1.0\r\n" % (self._tunnel_host,
        self._tunnel_port)
    connect_bytes = connect_str.encode("ascii")
    self.send(connect_bytes)
    for header, value in self._tunnel_headers.items():
        header_str = "%s: %s\r\n" % (header, value)
        header_bytes = header_str.encode("latin-1")
        self.send(header_bytes)
    self.send(b'\r\n')

    response = self.response_class(self.sock, method=self._method)
    (version, code, message) = response._read_status()

    if code != http.HTTPStatus.OK:
        self.close()
        raise OSError("Tunnel connection failed: %d %s" % (code,
                                                           message.strip()))
```

I've debugged it such that I know that the code is throwing the OSError and it only gives the status code and the message. What I want to do is also pass in the `response` to that exception but at the same time I don't want to change the library because I'm hoping there's a way to do this without changing the lib

Comment: what does `r.text` contain after the request ?

Comment: @hingev It throws an exception during the execution of that get request so I don't think it would contain anything if I were to catch the exception

Comment: The redirect will succeed sometimes, right?  So you don't want to disable redirection I guess.  Have you looked at the exception to make sure there isn't information in it?  I'm surprised that Requests does this. - seems it should return the 302 as the status code, and then you could look at the history for what happened.

Comment: @Steve Yeah I don't want to disable the redirection. I took a look at their exception handling and it only gives me the status code and the error message whereas I want the actual response body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me from the source code for the ProxyError exception object in Requests like that object should have the request in it.  I know you said you think it doesn't, but this shows that it is at least putting a `response` field in there, even if it were to end up `null`.

I would have maybe put this in comments, but you can't format code there.  This sure seems though like it would give you what you want:

```
class RequestException(IOError):
    """There was an ambiguous exception that occurred while handling your
    request.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize RequestException with `request` and `response` objects."""
        response = kwargs.pop('response', None)
        self.response = response
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        if (response is not None and not self.request and
                hasattr(response, 'request')):
            self.request = self.response.request
        super(RequestException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ConnectionError(RequestException):
    """A Connection error occurred."""

class ProxyError(ConnectionError):
    """A proxy error occurred."""
```

So seeing this code, it seems like something like this would work:

```
try:
    ...
    session.get(url=url, headers=req_headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, timeout=30)
    ...
except ProxyError as ex:
    the_response = ex.response
    .. do something with the response ..
```

Comment: Don't know who upvoted me, but @Tim, I'm really curious to hear if this worked for you.  I love the Requests library.  I want to hear that it didn't let you down.

Comment: let me give it a try. I also updated my code to show where the exception is specifically being thrown

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, it just gave me the status code & msg

Comment: There's no `response` attribute in the exception object, eh?  It sure seems like there should be as its constructor (in its `RequestException` parent object) seems to put it there.

Comment: Are you getting a `ProxyError` as the exception type you're getting back? - I'm guessing that you aren't...the message shows that, but you're getting something else.  It could be that you can get to that exception deeper in the main exception object. - Can you print the full exception with stacktrace and post it here?

Comment: I printed the entire error object and it gave me this: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somehost', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 302 Object Moved')))`. It is indeed a `ProxyError` but it doesn't seem to have the response object

Comment: It says `Caused by ProxyError` which I think means that the ProxyError is one level down in the chain of exceptions.  Maybe it's there for you to get at.  If I could reproduce this, I'd be checking it out myself.

Comment: so it seems like the issue is actually not with `Requests` but is with python itself. The error is initially thrown inside `python3.7/http/client.py` inside the `_tunnel` function. I guess there isn't much I can do about this then. I appreciate all your help though :-). Marking this as the correct answer since it helped me identify the problem and the "solution"

Comment: So you're sure that the ProxyError object isn't accessible inside the main exception huh?  Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to use Request's `history` functionality to access that object, and Request's standard APIs to go from there:

https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

> By default Requests will perform location redirection for all verbs
>   except HEAD.
>
> We can use the history property of the Response object to track
>   redirection.
>
> The Response.history list contains the Response objects that were
>   created in order to complete the request. The list is sorted from the
>   oldest to the most recent response.

```
r = requests.get('http://github.com/')

r.url 'https://github.com/'

r.status_code 200

r.history [<Response [301]>]
```

Will `headers` then not give you what you need?

https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#advanced

```
>>> r.headers
{'content-length': '56170', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-cache':
'HIT from cp1006.eqiad.wmnet, MISS from cp1010.eqiad.wmnet', 'content-encoding':
'gzip', 'age': '3080', 'content-language': 'en', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding,Cookie',
'server': 'Apache', 'last-modified': 'Wed, 13 Jun 2012 01:33:50 GMT',
'connection': 'close', 'cache-control': 'private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0,
must-revalidate', 'date': 'Thu, 14 Jun 2012 12:59:39 GMT', 'content-type':
'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'x-cache-lookup': 'HIT from cp1006.eqiad.wmnet:3128,
MISS from cp1010.eqiad.wmnet:80'}
```

Comment: I'm trying to assign `r = session.get(url)` but because it's throwing an exception, `r` isn't getting assigned anything so I can't find a way to access the history either

Comment: Ah. I should have read more carefully. Apologies. Are you able to use `head` instead of `get`?

Comment: No problem, I tried using `head` and I ran into the same issue. Same exception being thrown with no response object attached to the exception object

Comment: Please don't use a code block for something that isn't code, especially if it kinda/sorta looks like code.  Your first code block is really confusing.  You're just showing what would be in the response, right?